# Token is not imported from the @solana/spl-token

Tags: token, anchor, solana

[image]

I can't import token from the library.
What's the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of `@solana/spl-token` exports all the actions that were originally on the `Token` class, giving more flexibility to the client.

If you want to use the old `Token` class, you can do the following:

```
npm install @solana/spl-token@0.1.8
```

Otherwise you'll find documentation on `@solana/spl-token@0.2.0` at the [SPL docs](https://spl.solana.com/token) and [Solanacookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html)